# Luna theme help - product images

Tags: image, product

I'm using Luna theme and would like the images on the home and product pages to be viewed as squares (to fit the theme) and then viewed as the original landscape photos when the product is clicked on. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is super vague, but I assume this is your solution:

Ripping from the source after viewing the template, this is an example from the "Products" page. Here is the original code:

```
<li id="product_9230867" class="product">
  <a href="/product/mobile-ready" title="View Mobile Ready">
    <div class="product_header">
      <h2>Mobile Ready</h2>
      <span class="dash"></span>            
      <h3><span class="currency_sign">$</span>20.00</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="product_thumb">
      <img src="http://images.cdn.bigcartel.com/bigcartel/product_images/95861562/max_w-560/MobileRun.png" class="fade_in" alt="Image of Mobile Ready">
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Change the "href" of the link to an image url like this:

```
<li id="product_9230867" class="product">
  <a href="THE_URL_TO_YOUR_IMAGE" title="View Mobile Ready">
    <div class="product_header">
      <h2>Mobile Ready</h2>
      <span class="dash"></span>            
      <h3><span class="currency_sign">$</span>20.00</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="product_thumb">
      <img src="http://images.cdn.bigcartel.com/bigcartel/product_images/95861562/max_w-560/MobileRun.png" class="fade_in" alt="Image of Mobile Ready">
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Now, if you want it to pop-up really pretty, you're going to need another solution. If you want a better solution, I'd suggest asking a more clear question with examples of what you've tried already.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. Apologies for the vague question, I'm new to anything web based and am not sure of the best ways to ask things.
This is very helpful though, thank you.

Comment: Could you please select this as the answer to help other people having the same problem?